# Must I use inner join if I want to use MAX() value as a "where" condition?

Tags: sql

My table is like this:

```
ProductID   ProductName     SupplierID  CategoryID  Unit                 Price
1           Chais           1           1           10 boxes x 20 bags   18
2           Chang           1           1           24 - 12 oz bottles   19
3           Aniseed Syrup   1           2           12 - 550 ml bottles  10
4           Chef Anton's 
            Cajun Seasoning 2           2           48 - 6 oz jars       21.35
5           Chef Anton's 
            Gumbo Mix       2           2           36 boxes             25
```

I copy it from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

I tried the simple version of `MAX()` function test, it works. But when I use the `HighestPrice` in the `WHERE` condtion as following:

```
SELECT
    MAX(Price) AS HighestPrice,
    SupplierID
FROM Products
GROUP BY SupplierID
WHERE HighestPrice>20;
```

The sytem report ERROR as:

> Error: misuse of aggregate: MAX()

Does it mean I must use inner join to get what I want?

Comment: yes, thanks everyone. We need use having clause for any aggregate function's value condition. This is a common sense, I forget it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query should work:

```
SELECT SupplierID, MAX(Price) AS HighestPrice    
FROM Products
GROUP BY SupplierID
HAVING MAX(Price) > 20;
```

following is the correct syntax of writing any SQL query:

```
SELECT column_name1,
       SUM(column_name2)
FROM   table_name
WHERE  [CONDITION]
GROUP BY column_name1
HAVING (arithematic function condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **having** instead of where .
Where is always used before group by statement. It is way to filter the data which is already available with us whereas having is used after group by statement because it is applied on the data which we are in process of making.

```
SELECT MAX(Price) AS HighestPrice, SupplierID   
FROM Products 
Group By SupplierID 
having MAX(Price) > 20;
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 1):

By way of explanation of **G.arima**’s answer above:

When you use `GROUP BY`, you effectively create a new virtual table which contains only the `GROUP BY` fields as well as summaries.

There are two filter clauses, `WHERE` and `HAVING`, but they have a distinct role.

- `WHERE` filters the original table. This gives you the formula `FROM … WHERE …`
- `HAVING` filters the groups. This gives you the formula `GROUP BY … HAVING …`

What you ask is OK, but the clause is the wrong one. As **G.arima** says, you should use `HAVING`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. If you specifically want to use where condition for highest price instead of having clause as given by G.arima with max function again. Do this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT
    MAX(Price) AS HighestPrice,
    SupplierID
FROM Products
GROUP BY SupplierID
) a
WHERE HighestPrice>20;
```

Hope it helps :-)